# RAILS ERROR : SyntaxError in ResumesController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I start my rails server And run resume builder I'm getting the following error:

root/app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

root/app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:121: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

root/app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:131: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Heres my resumes_controller.rb file lines 25 - 40

```
     # GET /resume/1
     # GET /resume/1.json
     def show
@resume = current_user.resumes.find(params[:id])
layout = current_user.resumes.find(params[:id]).layout || "application"
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @resume }
  format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "file_name",
    :layout   => "resumes/#{layout}.pdf.erb",
    :temwkhtmltopdfplate => "resumes/pdf_layouts/show.html.erb",
    :wkhtmltopdf  => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s,
  end
end
end
```

and heres my line 111 - 124

```
     def short_link
@resume = Resume.where(short_link: params[:short_link]).first
layout = @resume.layout || "application"
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {  render layout: @resume.layout }# show.html.erb
  format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "file_name",
    :layout   => "resumes/#{layout}.pdf.erb",
    :template => "resumes/pdf_layouts/show.html.erb",
    :wkhtmltopdf  => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s,
  end
end
end
```

and finally lines 126-131

```
      private
  def correct_user
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(user)
  end
  end
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two first: Remove coma after:

```
:wkhtmltopdf  => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s,
```

Last one: will need more context - you have unclosed block somewhere.

Comment: Wow Awesome solves the first two like you said Thanks.
although the last error is still on

Comment: @HabeebSulu - We'll need to see more of the last code. Unfortunately, this error is usually quite hard to find - you've opened a block somewhere, which has not been closed. It might be class definition, some method, any `do end` loop. There's no way to find the error from the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks BroiSatse the error has vanished, now a new one has popped up.
Im testing a script on localhost and im much of a novice on Ruby. 
heres the error
Showing C:/Sites/Resumonk-master/app/views/resumes/_form.html.erb where line #67 raised: 

root//app/views/resumes/_form.html.erb:67: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
...=  f.fields_for :educations, do |education_form| @output_buf...

Comment: @HabeebSulu - get rid of coma after `:education`: `= f.fields_for :educations, do`

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME BRO
I CANT THANK YOU ENOUGH